# Why changing recursion function into explicitly using stack can avoid stack overflow?

Tags: memory, recursion

> Although depth-first-search may best be thought of as a recursive
>   algorithm, recursion is not the best way to implement it. Indeed, the
>   code given above will fail for many large graphs by causing a stack
>   overflow. An alternative implementation is to replace the recursion
>   stack with an explicit stack

I read this from a page about depth first graph traversal [here](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/12_3_Graph_Traversal.html)

I'm wondering if this is because recursion function uses the stack part of memory; but the explicit stack, on the other hand, is declared on heap thus much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

True, This is a limitation due to the architecture of computer programs. The memory allocated for the implicit stack is more limited than the heap space. Due to the way recursion works - the stack space will be easily exhausted. That's why concept of explicit stack is what is generally used for big graphs.

Also by using the explicit stack we can use the entire memory space available to our program - which also reduces the possibility of getting out of memory